# Sort query by rand and post_date wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm cooking a simple script to display posts order by rand and post_date. I tried this below but it's doesn't work :

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=4&orderby=rand post_date&order=ASC);
```

Thank's in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but adding `post_date` after `rand` is simply useless...

SQL query will look like this :

```
SELECT [...] ORDER BY RAND() ASC, post_date ASC
```

`RAND()` will return float value, it will unlikely return twice the same value, so ordering by post_date (after rand) is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=4&orderby=post_date,rand&order=ASC);
```

Comment: No, you have to use space : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: Oh, yes. I know how build this SQL query, but WP_Query dont support it. Somethink like: orderby=post_date&order=RAND

Comment: it's "doesn't work", in effect i want rand all posts and AFTER apply sort by post_date, in sql is very easy, but with wordpress "api" is not very simple ...

Comment: It is simple, but useless in your case. My answer has been updated to explain why.